# Instantiating protected class from outside package

Tags: java, oop, generics

I have rewritten the Binary Search Tree code found in the following links to work generically - the class will work with any type parameter.
http://www.informatics.susx.ac.uk/courses/dats/DataStructures/SearchTree.java
http://www.informatics.susx.ac.uk/courses/dats/teach/code/demos/SearchTreeDemo.java

I placed my generic SearchTree.java in a package named mysearchtree, and imported that into SearchTreeDemo.java.

SearchTree.java contains:
Abstract class SearchTree.
Concrete class EmptyTree, which has a protected constructor.
Concrete class NodeTree, which also has a protected constructor.

The original, non-generic coding for the SearchTree abstract class was that a client of the code would instantiate an EmptyTree object through a static method as below:

```
public abstract class SearchTree {
    /**
     * Returns an empty tree.
     */
    public static SearchTree empty() {
        return new EmptyTree();
    }

    // more code
}
```

This would have been used as follows:

```
SearchTree t = SearchTree.empty();
t = t.add( new String("hello") );
```

When working with generics, I have re-written the class to have the following structure:

```
public abstract class SearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    public abstract boolean isEmpty();
    public abstract int numNodes();
    public abstract boolean contains(T key);
    public abstract SearchTree<T> add(T item);
    public abstract SearchTree<T> remove(T item);
    public abstract String toString();
}
```

The original plan of providing a static method that would return an EmptyTree will not work generically (you can't use the generic type parameters of the class in a static method).

My question is: How do I provide a type-safe way of allowing a client of this code to instantiate a EmptyTree from outside the package (or some other equivalent mechanism that would replace the `SearchTree t = SearchTree.empty()` code)?

**Update:**

I have tried the following, but get an error:

```
public static <U> SearchTree<U> createSearchTree() { return new EmptyTree<U>(); }
```

Errors:

```
./mysearchtree/SearchTree.java:7: type parameter U is not within its bound
    public static <U> SearchTree<U> createSearchTree() { return new EmptyTree<U>(); }
                                 ^
./mysearchtree/SearchTree.java:7: type parameter U is not within its bound
    public static <U> SearchTree<U> createSearchTree() { return new EmptyTree<U>(); }
                                                                              ^
2 errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this what you are looking for?  A parametrized method.

```
public static <Y extends Comparable<Y>> SearchTree<Y> empty() {
   return new SearchTree<Y>();
}
```

Comment: This is perfect - I tried this, but forgot to give Y the bound of extends Comparable<Y>. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the constructors are protected, the only way I can think of would be either the singleton or factory patterns (the latter being much more logical).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've just started learning design patterns. Would you be able to briefly explain how the factory pattern could be applied here? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe pass the class in to your staic method?